# Datepicker has probably the wrong style

Tags: android, android-datepicker

Why does my datepicker doesn't look like a normal one with 3 of those scroll things?

[image: http://i.imgur.com/lk2ZddE.jpg]

Code:

```
<DatePicker android:id="@+id/datePicker1" 
            style="android:datePicker1" 
            android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
```

Comment: can you post your code so we can help you

Comment: run the code on different devices and check

Comment: this is in my layout.xml but the problem is this is the standard datepicker. Every guide i read I have just use the standard datepicker and he looks different
<DatePicker
        android:id="@+id/datePicker1"
        style="android:datePicker1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

Comment: mustn´t it be something like: @android:style/datePicker1 , or @style/datePicker1 if You have the style declared by Yourself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Datepicker is a bit buggy from android 3.2 and up. Here's some code that will extend and modify the datepicker:

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.util.AttributeSet;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.ViewParent;
import android.widget.DatePicker;

public class CustomDatePicker extends DatePicker
{
    public CustomDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int
defStyle)
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);
    }

    public CustomDatePicker(Context context, AttributeSet attrs)
    {
        super(context, attrs);
    }

    public CustomDatePicker(Context context)
    {
        super(context);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onInterceptTouchEvent(MotionEvent ev)
    {
        /* Prevent parent controls from stealing our events once we've
gotten a touch down */
        if (ev.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            ViewParent p = getParent();
            if (p != null)
                p.requestDisallowInterceptTouchEvent(true);
        }

        return false;
    }
}
```

And to utilise it with XML:

```
<view android:id="@+id/datePicker" android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
android:layout_height="wrap_content" class="YOUR_PACKAGE.CustomDatePicker"   
 android:calendarviewshown="false">
        </view>
```

I've always used a custom view when I put it directly in my XML layout. Might be bad practice, I'm not sure. I'd appreciate a comment from someone if it is.

Comment: @user3310242 .... Please click the answer accepted ... if it resolved your question so that it may be helpful for others in future who come across similar problem

Comment: @user3310242 You're welcome. Additionally, you may want to research different ways of implementing this. You can modify it slightly and use it to extend `timePicker`.